# Tangent space of a differential manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I think that it's well-known result that for a differential map $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ that describes a compact regular submanifold $M$ of dimension $(m-1)$ (hyperplane) you get that its tangent space in any $p \in M$ is $$T_p(M) = Ker(d(f)_p)$$

My question is if also $T_p(M)$ can be understood as the orthogonal vector space of the one generated by the vector $\vec{0p}$, that is, the line $span_{\mathbb{R}}\{\vec{0p}\}$.

At least I think that is true for the $1,2$-dimensional spheres and the cylinder.

But for example for the torus or an ellipse?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: I believe it means "the vector, in $\Bbb R^m$, from the origin to the point $p$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In $\Bbb R^2$, consider the function 
$$
f(x, y) = (x-3)^2 + y^2 - 1
$$
The zero-set of this function is the circle $C$ of radius $1$ and center $(3, 0)$, so it contains the point $p = (3, 1)$ for instance. The tangent space at $p$ is the line through $p$ parallel to the $x$-axis, so every vector in that space is orthogonal to $[0, 1]$.

On the other hand, the vector $0p$ is $[3, 1]$, which is orthogonal only to the zero-vector in $T_p(C)$.

Comment: Thanks John! :)